# bringing lgb model accuracy closer to xgb's

Tags: xgboost, lightgbm, optuna

I set up the following parameters for tuning a `xgboost` model

```
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, y_train_cost)
dvalid = xgb.DMatrix(X_valid, y_valid_cost)

prm = {
  "objective": "reg:squarederror",
  "tree_method": "exact",
  "booster": "gbtree",
  "gamma": 1,                                                             
  
  "eta": trial.suggest_loguniform("eta", 1E-5, 0.3),                      
  "alpha": trial.suggest_loguniform("alpha", .1, 1.),                     
  
  "subsample": trial.suggest_uniform("subsample", 0.2, 0.8),              
  "colsample_bytree": trial.suggest_uniform("colsample_bytree", 0.2, 0.8),
  "max_depth" : trial.suggest_int("max_depth", 3, 6, step=1),             
  "min_child_weight": trial.suggest_int("min_child_weight", 2, 10, step=2)
}

bst = xgb.train(prm, dtrain=dtrain, evals=[(dvalid,"valid")], verbose_eval=False, 
                        num_boost_round=200, early_stopping_rounds=20)
self._booster = bst
```

I then switched to `lightgbm` and tried to tune the same model using the following parameters

```
lgb_train = lgb.Dataset(X_train, label=y_train_cost)
lgb_valid = lgb.Dataset(X_valid, label=y_valid_cost, reference=lgb_train)

prm = {
  "objective": "regression",
  "boosting_type": "gbdt",
  "metric": {"rmse"},                                                    
  "force_row_wise": True,
  "verbose": 0,
  
  "learning_rate": trial.suggest_loguniform("learning_rate",1E-5,0.3),   
  "lambda_l1": trial.suggest_loguniform("lambda_l1",.1,1.),              
  
  "num_leaves": trial.suggest_categorical("num_leaves", [15,31,63,127]),
  "bagging_fraction": trial.suggest_uniform("bagging_fraction",0.4,0.8), 
  "bagging_freq": 5,
  "feature_fraction": trial.suggest_uniform("feature_fraction",0.2,0.5), 
  "min_data_in_leaf": trial.suggest_int("min_data_in_leaf",10,50,step=5) 
}

bst = lgb.train(prm, lgb_train, num_boost_round=200, 
                valid_sets=lgb_valid, callbacks=[lgb.early_stopping(stopping_rounds=20,verbose=False)])
self._booster = bst
```

The `xgboost` model is almost 3% better in terms of MAPE which is the metric I am using in `Optuna` to score trials.   I would appreciate thoughts on how I should change the `lightgbm` parameters to bring it closer to `xgboost`.

Answer (score 0):

Also tune `"max_depth" : trial.suggest_int("max_depth", 3, 6, step=1),` for lightgbm.

Other options:

```
"num_leaves": trial.suggest_int("num_leaves", 4, 200, step=1),
"max_depth" : trial.suggest_int("max_depth", 3, 100, step=1)
```

and increase optuna number of trials.